# Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}$ for $a_{n}\gt 0$. Show that $\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac1{t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lfloor ta_{n}\rfloor =\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}$ be a series of positive terms. Show that  $$\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac1{t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lfloor ta_{n}\rfloor =\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}$$

So this is what I could come up with. I hope it's right

$$ ta_{1}-1 \lt \lfloor ta_{1}\rfloor \le ta_{1}$$
$$ ta_{2}-1 \lt \lfloor ta_{2}\rfloor \le ta_{2}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$ ta_{n}-1 \lt \lfloor ta_{n}\rfloor \le ta_{n}$$
$$\vdots$$
Dividing with $t$ we get 
$$a_{1}-\frac 1{t} \lt \frac{\lfloor ta_{1}\rfloor}{t} \le a_{1} $$
$$a_{2}-\frac 1{t} \lt \frac{\lfloor ta_{2}\rfloor}{t} \le a_{2} $$
$$\vdots$$
$$a_{n}-\frac 1{t} \lt \frac{\lfloor ta_{n}\rfloor}{t} \le a_{n} $$
$$\vdots$$

If we use the limit when $t \to \infty$ in every inequality and  then by summing all of them we get
 $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n} \le \lim_{t\to \infty}\frac1{t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lfloor ta_{n}\rfloor \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}  $$
So the limit is 
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac1{t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lfloor ta_{n}\rfloor =\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n} $$

I'm not very sure if this is right. Can somebody tell me what to do or does someone has another method?

Comment: There are inequalities that you need to use such as $\lfloor a_n \rfloor \lfloor t \rfloor \leq \lfloor ta_n \rfloor $

Comment: Is this right now?

Comment: What level class is this?  If this is an elementary calculus class, your answer is probably sufficient.  If this is an analysis class (or if you want to be 100% correct), you will need to justify moving limits in and out of the summation.  If interchanging limits is not a topic you've discussed in your class thus far, then your solution should be sufficient.

Comment: We've discussed it but only on finite terms. Can I move the limits when I am working with infinite terms?

Comment: Something is missing.  When you  sum $a_n-\frac{1}{t}$ you end up with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n-\frac{\infty}{t}$.  How did you get rid of $\frac{\infty}{t}$, since the limit is $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$?

Comment: That's where I'm stuck. First I take the limit of each inequality then I sum it, but I'm not very sure if it's right moving the limits out of the sum when I'm working with infinite terms. That is where I need a little help

Comment: Do you know $\limsup$ and $\liminf$? The simplest method I can think of is to separate it into $\limsup_{t\to \infty} \dotsc \leqslant \sum a_n$ and $\liminf \dotsc \geqslant \sum a_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help: Let $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ and assume $S<\infty.$ Let $\epsilon>0.$ Then there exists $N$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n > S-\epsilon/2.$ Choose $t_0$ such that $N/t<\epsilon/2$ for $t\ge t_0.$ Then $t\ge t_0$ implies

$$\frac1{t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lfloor ta_{n}\rfloor \ge \frac1{t}\sum_{n=1}^N\lfloor ta_{n} \rfloor \ge \frac1{t}\sum_{n=1}^N (ta_{n}-1) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_{n} -N/t > S-\epsilon/2 - \epsilon/2 = S-\epsilon.$$

Comment: Thank you very useful. So should I prove the other side of the inequality ie $\frac1{t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lfloor ta_{n}\rfloor \le\frac1{t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty ta_{n}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}=S$ or is this enough?

Comment: Yes, that's the easy side. And you still have the $S=\infty$ case to do.

Comment: Ok thank you again